# Designing IM Application Android Client and GO Server

Tags: android, rabbitmq, mqtt, instant-messaging

I want to build an IM application and i have seen many topologies that use MQTT and i thought about giving it a try.

The designs i have seen contains multiple clients that subscribe to a queue using WebSockets and one of them publish and the message broker filter by the topic which message goes to which client.

I didnt understand a few things,
First, Isn't that risky to expose the endpoint of the Broker to the outside world even though it's behind a load balancer?
And second, Is it better to use a Message broker or just a service with client that every X seconds will check for new messages.

Thanks guys in advance

Comment: Design questions like this tend to be opinion based which are off topic for Stackoverflow

Comment: I Don't agree with you at all about that, Understanding the risk of exposing an endpoint of message broker is not opinion based at all, and second in terms of performance and scalability i don't think that deciding if a message broker is the right choice is opinion based as well

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the exposing of message broker endpoints, I'd recommend TLS for secure connections.

Personally I wouldn't go the polling approach. I'd use the message broker because it's simply more efficient.